# improve performance of a double for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm doing some analysis where I'm analysing hundreds of data files, which are being analysed iteratively. Here is an examples of the sort of data that I have:

```
start_time = datenum('1990-01-01');
end_time = datenum('2009-12-31');
time = start_time:end_time;

datx = rand(length(time),1);
daty = datx-2;
```

where I have a time variable and two data variables.

After loading the data I then need to pass the data through a function. However, I need to do this by including firstly the data from year 1 only, then from years 1 to 2; 1 to 3, 1 to 4 and so on until I pass the data through the function for the entire series. This can be performed with a loop with the following:

```
% split into different years 
datev = datevec(time);
iyear = datev(:,1);
unique_year = unique(iyear);
for k = 1:length(unique_year);
    idx = find(iyear >= unique_year(1)  & iyear <= unique_year(k));

    % select data for year
    d_time = time(idx);
    d_datx = datx(idx); 
    d_daty = daty(idx); 

    % now select individual years from this subset
    datev2 = datevec(d_time);
    iyear2 = datev2(:,1);
    unique_year2 = unique(iyear2);
    for k2 = 1:length(unique_year2);
        idx2 = find(iyear2 == unique_year2(k2));
        % select data for year
        d_time2 = d_time(idx2);
        d_datx2 = d_datx(idx2); 
        d_daty2 = d_daty(idx2);   

        % pass through some function
        mae_out = some_function(d_datx2, d_daty2);
        mae(k2) = mae_out;    
    end
    mean_mae(k) = mean(mae);
end

function mae = some_function(datx, daty)
    mae = mean(abs(datx - daty));
end
```

Note here that I'm using a very simple function as an example, and the actual function is more complex.

Having two loops like this takes a long time to run on my actual data. Is there a better/faster way that I can perform the above, possibly without loops?

Answer (score 0):

If you record the previous result, you do not need the inner loop. You are currently computing a total of `(20+21)/2 = 210` iterations, but you only need to compute `20`. The key here is that `mean(a(1:k)) == (mean(a(1:k-1))*(k-1) + a(k)) / k` (by the definition of mean). Another optimization is to use logical indexing instead of find. It takes up a bit more space, but is much faster.

```
% split into different years 
datev = datevec(time);
iyear = datev(:,1);
unique_year = unique(iyear);
for k = 1:length(unique_year);
    idx = (iyear == unique_year(k));

    % select data for year
    d_time = time(idx);
    d_datx = datx(idx); 
    d_daty = daty(idx); 

    mae_out = some_function(d_datx, d_daty);
    if k == 1
        mean_mae(k) = mean_out;
    else
        mean_mae(k) = (mean_mae(k-1) * (k-1) + mean(mean_out)) / k;
    end
end

function mae = some_function(datx, daty)
    mae = mean(abs(datx - daty));
end
```

As you can see, this should give you approximately 20x or more speedup.